# Operator Commutativity $\hat{L}_{z}$; $\hat{p}^{2}$; $[\hat{p}^{2}, \hat{L}]$

Tags: linear-algebra

Define:

$$\hat{p}^{2}= \hat{p}^{2}_{x}+\hat{p}^{2}_{y}+\hat{p}^{2}_{z}= -\hbar^{2} \Delta$$

$$\hat{L}_{z}= xp_{y}-yp_{x}= -i\hbar \big(x\frac{\partial}{\partial y} - y \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \big)$$

consider the Hamiltonian in three dimensions with a potential that depends only on the distance from the origin:

$$\hat{H} = \frac{\hat{p}^{2}}{2m} + \hat{V}(r), r=(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2})^{1/2}$$

Since: $ \hat{p}^{2}\hat{L}_{z} = -\hbar^{2}\Delta\big(-i\hbar(x\frac{\partial}{\partial y} - y\frac{\partial}{\partial x})\big) = i\hbar^{3}(\frac{\partial ^{2}}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial ^{2}}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial ^{2}}{\partial z})(x\frac{\partial}{\partial y} - y \frac{\partial}{\partial x}) = 0 $ and $\hat{L}_{z}\hat{p}^{2}=(-i\hbar (x\frac{\partial}{\partial y}- y\frac{\partial}{\partial x})(-\hbar^{2}\Delta)=i\hbar^{3}(x\frac{\partial}{\partial y} - y \frac{\partial }{\partial x})(\frac{\partial ^{2}}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial z}) = 0$

$$[\hat{p}^{2},\hat{L}_{z}] = \hat{p}^{2}\hat{L}_{z} - \hat{L}_{z}\hat{p}^{2} = 0-0 = 0$$

The operator $\hat{L}_{z}$ commutes with $\hat{p}^{2}$.

And $\hat{p}^{2} \hat{V} = -\hbar^{2}(\frac{\partial^{2} \hat{V}}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial^{2} \hat{V}}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial^{2} \hat{V}}{\partial z})$ together ith $\hat{V} \hat{p}^{2} = \hat{V}(-\hbar^{2}\Delta) = -\hbar^{2}(\frac{\partial^{2} \hat{V}}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial^{2} \hat{V}}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial ^{2} \hat{V}}{\partial z})$

$$[\hat{p}^{2},\hat{V}]=\hat{p}^{2}\hat{V}- \hat{V}\hat{p}^{2} = 0$$

**Edit** : I tried showing that $\hat{L}_{z}$ commutes with $\hat{V}$ using Norberts method: $(\hat{V}\hat{L}_{z})(f) = V(-i\hbar(x\frac{\partial (f)}{\partial y} - y \frac{\partial (f)}{\partial x}))$ and $(\hat{L}_{z}\hat{V})(f)= \hat{L}_{z}(V(r)(f)) =-i\hbar(x\frac{\partial}{\partial y} - y\frac{\partial}{\partial x})(V(r)f) = -i\hbar((f)x\frac{\partial V}{\partial y} + (V)x\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}-(V)y\frac{\partial (f)}{\partial x} - (f)y \frac{\partial (V)}{\partial x})$  Why are they not the same?

I have never worked with operators before, so can you tell me if this is alright? I will greatly appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are considering operators, which are by definition acts on functions. If you want to compare two operators you must compare results of applying them to all allowed functions. Assume that this operators defined on space of smooth functions in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Then
for all smooth function $f$ we have
$$
(\hat{p}^2 \hat{V})(f)=\hat{p}^2(Vf)=-\hbar^2\Delta(Vf)=
-\hbar^{2}\left(\frac{\partial^{2} (Vf)}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^{2} (Vf)}{\partial y^2} + \frac{\partial ^{2} (Vf)}{\partial z^2}\right)=
$$
$$
-\hbar^{2}\left(f\frac{\partial^{2} V}{\partial x^2} + f\frac{\partial^{2} V}{\partial y^2} + f\frac{\partial ^{2} V}{\partial z^2}+V\frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial x^2} + V\frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial y^2} + V\frac{\partial ^{2} f}{\partial z^2}+2\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}+2\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial V}{\partial y}+2\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\frac{\partial V}{\partial z}\right)=
$$
$$
-\hbar^{2}\left(f\Delta V+V\Delta f+2\langle\nabla f,\nabla V\rangle\right)
$$
On the other hand
$$
(\hat{V}\hat{p}^2)(f)=\hat{V}(\hat{p}^2(f))=\hat{V}\left(-\hbar^{2}\left(\frac{\partial^{2} (f)}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^{2} (f)}{\partial y^2} + \frac{\partial ^{2} (f)}{\partial z^2}\right)\right)=-\hbar^{2}V\Delta f
$$
Thus we see that $\hat{V}\hat{p}^2\neq\hat{p}^2\hat{V}$

Comment: thx to you norbert

Answer (score 0):

The second equality is wrong:
$\hat{V}\hat{p}^{2} \neq -\hbar^{2}\left(\sum_{i=0}^{3}\dfrac{\partial^{2}\hat{V}}{\partial x_{i}^{2}}\right)$. You have already assumed in this "equality" that the operators commute. Actually, I don't think that it is necessary in quatum mechanics to assume that you have a potential operator. Normally, the potential simply takes the form of a function. So, drop the hat. But the spatial "variable" is an operator. I hope this helps you a bit further.

Comment: Thx. My scriptum says: Show that $\hat{L}_{z}$ also commutes with $\hat{V}$ if $\hat{V}=\hat{V}(r)$. I am not sure how to show this, and you just told me that what I have tried is wrong.